# Using nodes and Linked List

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to create a "linked list" and I'm running into trouble and I'm a little confused on how I am supposed to implement "nodes".

A collection of nodes that point to each other is considered a linked list, right? I'm trying to create a function that accepts an array along with it's size, and i'm supposed to take each element, and be able to sort it as I put it into a list, then put it back into the array ordered. How am I even supposed to do this? I know that a node holds a certain element, and a pointer to the next node. Is there already a structure in the STL, or do I have to make it from scratch?

Can anybody help me get started? (aside or addition to what I've already got). I also don't know how to go from elements of an array to elements of a node and how to sort them in order. I'm working with ints right now and I'm hoping to move to templates. Help would be much appreciated!

EDIT) This is a header file by the way...

```
using namespace std;

/***********************************************
 * NODE
 ***********************************************/
struct Node
{
   int data;
   Node * pNext;
};

/***********************************************
 * INSERTION SORT
 * Sort the items in the array
 **********************************************/
//template <class T>
void sortInsertion(int array[], int num)
{
   // Make sure we can list the elements unsorted
   cout << "Testing sortInsertion()...\n\n";
   cout << "Unsorted:\n";
   for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
      cout << "num "<< i + 1 << ": " << array[i] << endl;
   cout << endl;
   cout << "Sorted:\n";

   // Okay, make the head of the list...
   Node *pHead;

   // Loop through each element and insert it into the list, depending on order
   for (int i = 0; i < num; i++);

   // Loop through each node, and transfer each element into the array.
   for(const Node *p = pHead; p; p = p -> pNext)
   {
      int i = 0;
      array[i] = p -> data;
      i++;
   }
}
```

Comment: There is existing data structure in STL for you to do that. However you must not use STL because building things from scratch is the purpose of your assignment.

Comment: Oh yeah this is a partner assignment. My partner is actually making the "node" class container, and I am supposed to do the implementation. I want to use STL while his part isn't finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
 for (int i = 0; i < num; i++);
```

is equivalent of

```
i = num;
```

And this

for(const Node *p = pHead; p; p = p -> pNext)
   {
      int i = 0;
      array[i] = p -> data;
      i++;
   }

I think has a compile error - but if it did would be just setting the first item in `array`

But why not use the STL?

Comment: What is the library name for the STL? I couldn't find it

Comment: Start here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/ - Has sorting done. Lined lists and vecrtors

Comment: I did end up here earlier: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/, but I couldn't get and farther than that. I can't figure out how to use it in my own implementation. How do I go from an array, to a whole bunch of nodes...

Comment: So in the STL <list> library, does it implement nodes? Is that how it works?